# Gulp: Trouble setting browserSync and Watch

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I'm learning Gulp and NPM and decided to test myself by using Browser-Sync with a PHP project I'm working on (using XAMPP). I know Browser-Sync doesnt work with PHP files, but I wanted to use it with my .css files (and later on perhaps add Sass).

I installed npm, Gulp, Gulp-watch and Browser Sync to my project's root directory and all seemed fine.

I then created a gulp.js file with the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./"
        }
    });

    watch('css/*.css', function() {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

});
```

However, when I `gulp watch` a new browser window does open but just shows the `Cannot GET /` error.

Also, the URL shows `http://localhost:3002/` rather than `http://localhost:myproejct`

I read this may have something to do with my `baseDir` so tried:

```
baseDir: ""
baseDir: "./"
baseDir: "../myproject"
```

Would anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing way more than is necessary to do what you want. You can just use browsersync as a proxy layer over the top of your hosted site.

See the following example from the [docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line)

```
# Proxy a PHP app + serve static files & watch them
$ browser-sync start --proxy 'mylocal.dev' --serveStatic 'public' --files 'public'
```

I think this is what you will need, run it from the physical root of your site and replace `mylocal.dev` with your php server address

```
npm install browser-sync -g

browser-sync start --proxy 'mylocal.dev' --serveStatic 'css' --files 'css/*.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Assuming your target HTML file works if opened in the browser manually: One common cause of the `Cannot Get/` error is using an index file other than Browsersync's default expectation, `index.html`. Could that be the problem you're having? If you need a custom index file, you can set the `index` option:

```
browserSync.init({
    server: {
        baseDir: 'mybasedirectorypath',
        index: 'notindex.html'
    }
});
```

Fwiw, you can also do this more efficiently, and save yourself the weight of installing `gulp-watch` (this example adapted and simplified from this [Browsersync docs example](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-manual-reload)):

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('css/*.css').on('change',browserSync.reload)
});
```

---

As for using a custom url, check out https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/646 which has some solutions.